# Query in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I try to print a query through the java console but nothing comes out. this is my code someone could help me. 
I'm new to OrientDB and I'm just learning.
The query I need is to know the shortest path between two nodes and print this query on the Java console. It does not give me any errors but nothing comes out.

```
public class Graph {
    private static final String DB_PATH = "C:/OrientDataBase/shortest_path";
    static OrientGraphNoTx DBGraph;
    static OrientGraphFactory factory;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:"+DB_PATH);
        DBGraph = factory.getNoTx();
        HashMap<String, Vertex> nodes = new HashMap<String, Vertex>();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        Vertex v = DBGraph.addVertex("class:V");
        v.setProperty("vertexID", i+"");
        nodes.put(i+"", v);
    }


    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/OrientDataBase/sp1.csv"))) {
        int i=0;
        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) !=null ; ) {
            if(i==0){
                i++;
            }
            else{
            String[] vertices = line.split(",");
            String vertex1 = vertices[0];
            String vertex2 = vertices[1];
            String weight= vertices[2];
            vertex2 = vertex2.replaceAll(" ", "");

            Vertex v1 = nodes.get(vertex1);
            Vertex v2 = nodes.get(vertex2);


            Edge eLives = DBGraph.addEdge(null, v1, v2, "belongs");
            eLives.setProperty("weight", weight);
            System.out.println(v1+","+v2+","+weight);

            String query = "select expand(shortestPath) from (select shortestPath(#10:0,#10:2,BOTH))";

            Iterable<OrientVertex> res = DBGraph.command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute();

            while(res.iterator().hasNext()){
            OrientVertex v = res.iterator().next();
            System.out.println("rid: "+v.getId().toString()+"\tn:"+v.getProperty("n"));
            }

            }
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post. Note that once you post a question or answer to this site, those posts become part of the collective efforts of others who have also contributed to that content. Posts that are potentially useful to others should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances. Even if the post is no longer useful to the original author, that information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar problems in the future - this is the underlying philosophy of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and you have to put the ticks when you do the query so, it becomes:

```
String query = "select expand(shortestPath) from (select shortestPath(#10:0,#10:2,'BOTH'))";
```

[image]

I used this csv file.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Regards